# Scriptural references for the family goddess of Indian famous mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan

Tags: goddess, reference-request

The following [paragraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) says that Ramanujan credited his mathematical capabilities to the goddess [Namagiri Thayar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namagiri_Thayar)

> A deeply religious Hindu, **Ramanujan credited his substantial
>   mathematical capacities to divinity, and stated that the mathematical
>   knowledge he displayed was revealed to him by his family goddess**.
>   "An equation for me has no meaning," he once said, "unless it
>   expresses a thought of God."
>   .................................................................
>   .................................................................................................................................
>   Apparently, **Ramanujan's mother had a vivid dream in which the family
>   goddess, the deity of Namagiri**, commanded her "to stand no longer
>   between her son and the fulfilment of his life's purpose".

Does any scripture mentions about her? If yes, then which scripture mentions about her?

Comment: She is Goddess Lakshmi. Thayar is local name. For example, Alivel Mangathayar is name of Goddess Padmavathi who is avatar of Lakshmi.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, not alivel, alarmel

Comment: @ram ohh..Not sure why we write Alivel(u) in Telugu.